# Post to facebook page A as other facebook page B user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

After looking for hours, I cant find an answer to this question. Hopefully someone can help me out. I'm using the latest facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.0).

I have a fan page of a company (page A) and several people of that company have fan pages as well (page B, C, D etc.). The issue is we want to have the posts of the page B (and C and D) posted to page A, but the sender (post user) should be page user B.

**Can you post to a page wall A as another page user B?**

I've tried everything and have the following working:

- I have an access token of a admin user that is admin of all the pages
- I have an Extended access token to be able to do request automatically for 60 days
- I have an page token for all the pages from the /me/accounts request
- I have an array of all the wall posts of all the pages through /[page-id]/feed

The last part is looping over the array to post to the wall of page A as the users B, C or D.

I send a POST request to /[page-id-page-A]/feed with a message and the page token of page B. After the request I get an error:

**Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id**

Posting as page user B to the wall of page B works fine. Posting as Page user B to page A doesn't. The documentation isn't clear on if this is supposed to work, but from the facebook UI this is possible.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. The code  I'm using is below for anyone who wants to use it.

```
<?php
/* ************************
* Helper functions
************************ */
function sortbykey($a, $b) {
  return $a['time'] - $b['time'];
}

/* ************************
* Start app
************************ */
// Initialize Facebook
require_once("facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => '<appID>','secret' => '<appSecret>'));

// Get facebook user (if possible)
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

$login_params = array(
  'scope' => 'manage_pages,publish_stream',
  'redirect_uri' => '<app_url>/index.php'
);
if($user_id) {
  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {
    // Get user profile and extended access tokens for requests
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_params); 
    echo '<div class="login"><a href="' . $login_url . '">login</a></div>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {
  // No user, print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_params);
  echo '<div class="login"><a href="' . $login_url . '">login</a></div>';
}

if(isset($access_token) && !empty($access_token)){
  // Provide logout options
  $logout_url = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(); 
  echo '<div class="logout"><a href="' . $logout_url . '">logout</a></div>';

  // Get user pages and tokens
  $user_pages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts','GET');
  $page_tokens = array();
  foreach($user_pages['data'] as $page){
    $page_tokens[$page['id']] = $page['access_token'];
  }

  // Set challenger ID's and page ID
  $persons = array('page-ID-B','page-ID-C','page-ID-D');
  $page = 'page-ID-A';

  // Loop over persons and create stream of messages.
  $messages = array();
  foreach($persons as $person){
    $token = $page_tokens[$person];
    $feed = $facebook->api('/'.$person.'/feed','GET');
    foreach($feed['data'] as $status){
      // Add page token to message to post as page and time to sort by
      $status['token'] = $token;
      $status['time'] = strtotime($status['created_time']);
      // Only add messages that aren't imported yet
      if($status['time'] > $_SESSION['lastupdatetime']) {
        $messages[] = $status;
      }
    }
  }
  // Sort by time value in nested array
  usort($messages,"sortbykey");

  // Post messages to timeline
  foreach($messages as $status){

    // Post to MScHALLENGE page based on type
    switch($status['type']){
      case 'status':
      case 'link':

        // Build post data 
        $data = array();
        if(isset($status['message'])) $data['message'] = $status['message'];
        if(isset($status['link'])) $data['link'] = $status['link'];
        // Post to facebook
        if(!empty($data)){
          $data['access_token'] = $status['token'];
          $post = $facebook->api('/'.$page.'/feed','POST',$data);
        }

        break;

    }

    // Save last update time
    $_SESSION['lastupdatetime'] = $status['time'];
  }  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported as I have done some testing recently. Even if you are admin of *both* PageA and PageB, you cannot post on PageA as PageB (where the "voice" is set to PageB and the post is displayed as authored by PageB). The voice (ie. "authored by PageB") works on pages you admin and creates posts on the page with the voice belonging to the *same* page. At least that's how the API is behaving currently.